# Shell script which runs well in terminals not producing expected output in crontab

Tags: linux, shell, cron, automation

I'm trying to run a shell script using `cron` every 15 & 45 mins of the hour. But for some vague reasons it always produces empty strings while executed by `cron` whereas in when i run using terminals `./my_script.sh` it produces expected results. I read many of answers relating to this questions, but none could solve my problem.

codes:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 PATH=/bin:/home/mpadmin/bin:/opt/ant/bin:/opt/cc/bin:/opt/cvsconsole:/opt/cvsconsole:/opt/cvsconsole:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/var/mp/95930/scripts:/var/mp/95930/opt/bin:/opt/prgs/dlc101c/bin:/opt/cvsconsole
    tail -n 1000000 conveyor2.log | grep -P 'curingresult OK' | sed 's/FT\ /FT/g' |awk '{print $5 $13}' |sed 's/\"//g' | uniq | sort -n |uniq > /var/www/html/95910/master_list.txt
    tail -n 1000000 registration.log | grep -P 'TirePresent: 8' | sed 's/GT\ /GT/g' |awk '{print $7 $15}' |sed 's/\"//g' | uniq | sort -n |uniq > /var/www/html/95910/TBM_list.txt
```

my cron

```
# run 15 and 45 mins every hour, every day
15,47 * * * *   sh /var/mp/95910/log/update_master_list.sh
```

permissions:

all files are having read write and execute permissions for all users

Hope I have given all the relevant & necessary infos

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to change to the */var/mp/95910/log/* directory first...

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/mp/95910/log/
PATH=/bin:/home/mpadmin/bin:/opt/ant/bin:/opt/cc/bin:/opt/cvsconsole:/opt/cvsconsole:/opt/cvsconsole:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/var/mp/95930/scripts:/var/mp/95930/opt/bin:/opt/prgs/dlc101c/bin:/opt/cvsconsole
tail -n 1000000 conveyor2.log | grep -P 'curingresult OK' | sed 's/FT\ /FT/g' |awk '{print $5 $13}' |sed 's/\"//g' | uniq | sort -n |uniq > /var/www/html/95910/master_list.txt
tail -n 1000000 registration.log | grep -P 'TirePresent: 8' | sed 's/GT\ /GT/g' |awk '{print $7 $15}' |sed 's/\"//g' | uniq | sort -n |uniq > /var/www/html/95910/TBM_list.txt
```

or specify the file paths explicitly

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/bin:/home/mpadmin/bin:/opt/ant/bin:/opt/cc/bin:/opt/cvsconsole:/opt/cvsconsole:/opt/cvsconsole:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/var/mp/95930/scripts:/var/mp/95930/opt/bin:/opt/prgs/dlc101c/bin:/opt/cvsconsole
tail -n 1000000 /var/mp/95910/log/conveyor2.log | grep -P 'curingresult OK' | sed 's/FT\ /FT/g' |awk '{print $5 $13}' |sed 's/\"//g' | uniq | sort -n |uniq > /var/www/html/95910/master_list.txt
tail -n 1000000 /var/mp/95910/log/registration.log | grep -P 'TirePresent: 8' | sed 's/GT\ /GT/g' |awk '{print $7 $15}' |sed 's/\"//g' | uniq | sort -n |uniq > /var/www/html/95910/TBM_list.txt
```

Comment: but logs of the cron shows that the job is executed without any error here is the logs.                                                  Aug 10 18:40:01 ops1 CROND[12742]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib/sa/sa1 1 1) Aug 10 18:45:01 ops1 CROND[20869]: (root) CMD (sh /var/mp/95910/log/update_master_list.sh) Aug 10 18:45:01 ops1 CROND[20870]: (root) CMD (LANG=C LC_ALL=C /usr/bin/mrtg /etc/mrtg/mrtg.cfg --lock-file /var/lock/mrtg/mrtg_l --confcache-file /var/lib/mrtg/mrtg.ok

Comment: @sanoopJNair As far as I know, cron starts the scripts in the home directory. Try to put the following command `pwd > /tmp/debugPwd` to the beginning of the script and see the output. I guess there are no files conveyor2.log and registration.log in this directory. Thus the output of tail is empty.

Comment: OK I ll try it out hoping it works this time :) thanks for the explanation

Comment: Yes you was right when I just changed directory in my script it started producing output. Thanks a ton